# Law of large numbers and random matching

Tags: probability, random-variables

I learnt in Calc that law of large numbers is about the mean of a variable. I want to know whether this law also applies to income inequality measures. In particular, I have a sample with about 7000 observations. Each observation consists of incomes of 2 persons, one individual and their partner. Then I randomly re-match all these persons (I did this in Stata). Say now I have 100 new samples in which all persons are rematched in random ways. I want to know:

does the income inequality, as measured by Gini or other inequality measures, have a latent constant value that corresponds to the random-matching scenario? Can I calculate the mean of the Gini coefficients for all the 100 new samples and treat it as the Gini "when individuals in my sample is randomly rematched"?

Thank you!

Comment: I dont know what Gini is nor other details, but seems to me you have a well defined random variable.  I.e. you randomize some things and then do some complicated calculations resulting in a numeric value $G$ which depends on the randomization.  So $G$ has some unknown/complicated distribution.  But it also has a mean (unless it's infinite) and you can estimate this true mean by calculating the sample mean with a large sample size.  Whether $100$ samples is large enough to give a good estimate will depend on the details of the randomization and the calculations though...